# SQL Alchemy integration with node.js -Latency issues

Tags: python, node.js, sqlalchemy

My Team is working to re-build a cron job which was originally built using java,hibernate implementation acts as an ORM and implements cursor to load the reference data using the cron job into inmemory cache instance,we are trying to re-build this cron job using node.js by integrating with SQL Alchemy ORM ,But my team is complaining that they are facing latency issues and trying to move away from using SQL Alchemy ,could anybody assist us in resolving these latency issues

Please find their finding below related to integration of SQLAlchemy ORM (python) with Nodejs :

Currently child process is being used to spawn the python SQLAlchemy code which is having a response time of around ~13s for each query result.
Cursor Query support using fetchAll method (with and without arraySize Parameter)
Implemented Count(*) query and captured the response time - around ~10s.
Implemented Select * query - using SQLAlchemy cursor support - there are issues since we using child process to communicate between python and NodeJS, we are not able to have an reference to the cursor variable to fetch the next available data.
Native Python Implementation of cursor query works, but since we are having child process in between, we aren't able to have a feasible solution.

Query - SELECT * FROM TABLEXYZ WHERE ID1 = 35001669 AND ID2 !=35001668;
Time taken - 2021-05-07T09:03:14.160 - 2021-05-07T09:03:00.193 - 14 seconds
Used "python-shell" node module - not much improvement in response time.
Query - SELECT * FROM TABLEXYZ WHERE ID1 = 35001669 AND ID2 !=35001668;

Time taken - 2021-05-11T02:48:55.809Z - 2021-05-11T02:48:44.485Z ~10 seconds

Could anybody help in resolving these integration related latency issues quickly

Comment: I think you will need to include a lot more information.  What database are you using? What is the performance when you call the query directly from the native database client?  Are you starting Python in the subprocess and then calling the query and recording that total time?

Comment: If you could include a larger code sample to that would be better.

Comment: We are usilng DB2 database hosted over mainframe Z/OS,Team is mentioning that query through local DB client is fare more faster than query through SQL Alchemy ORM tool